# vanishing of higher algebraic de Rham cohomology and sheaves of differentials for singular curves

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-curves, singularity-theory, positive-characteristic, derham-cohomology

I'm looking for some results or references about [de Rham cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_de_Rham_cohomology#de_Rham_cohomology) of curves in less-than-optimal cases. The two vanishing results I care about are:

- $H^{k}_{\text{dR}}(X) = 0$ for $k>2$, since $H^{\bullet}_{\text{dR}}$ is a [Weil cohomology theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_cohomology_theory) (in characteristic zero), which implies the result if $X$ is a *smooth*, *projective* curve over $\text{char}(k)=0$.
- Before taking cohomology, we also have the vanishing $\Omega^i_{X/k}=0$ for $i>1$.

What I would like to know is under what conditions these vanishing statements remain true when allowing one or more of the following hypothesis relaxations:

- Smooth $\to$ singular (or nonsmooth) (even reducible, but still connected)
- Projective $\to$ quasiprojective
- Characteristic $0$ $\to$ arbitrary characteristic.

Unfortunately I've been unsuccesful in finding proofs or references, or in proving statements myself. So I would appreciate some help.

Comment: For $X$ a curve with one ordinary double point $p$, $\Omega ^2_{X/k}$ is nonzero (it is isomorphic to $k(p)$).

Comment: @abx ok, thank you. My calculations suggested this, but I was unsure of myself. And how about the cohomology? Is there anywhere I can see these calculations carried out?

Comment: See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256379/naive-de-rham-cohomology-fails-for-singular-varieties?noredirect=1&lq=1). You won't find many references, because  the approach in the smooth case clearly does not work in the singular case. For a correct approach, see Hartshorne's paper in Publ. IHES 45 (1975).

Comment: I am aware of that MO question and that paper, but so far I haven't been able to extract the desired information from them.